# How do I diagnose website connection issues with my router?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I'm having problems using a website, and it seems to be due to my router but I'm not sure how. When I try to connect to it, the browser just sits there and eventually the connection times out. If I turn off WiFi on my phone, I'm able to load the website fine. If I connect directly to my cable modem via ethernet (bypassing my router), I'm also able to load the website fine. So the problem seems to be due to my router somehow.

I've looked through my router's admin panel to see if I can find the problem. I tried turning off the Firewall (didn't help). I also changed the NAT type from Symmetric to Fullcone (that didn't help either). I couldn't find any other settings my router that could cause this problem, but it's possible I missed something.

My router is an [ASUS ZenWifi AX](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking-IoT-Servers/Whole-Home-Mesh-WiFi-System/ZenWiFi-WiFi-Systems/ZenWiFi-AX-XT8/). My cable modem is [Motorola 24x8](https://motorolanetwork.com/mb7621.html).

What else can I do to find the underlying cause of this issue?

Comment: What's your cable modem? if you can connect directly through it, it's likely to also be a simple router.

Comment: If I connect directly to my cable modem via Ethernet  ....   Do you by any chance have wireless isolation enabled?

Comment: @Tetsujin I added my cable modem to my question. My cable modem is a simple cable modem, and doesn't have any routing capabilities built in.

Comment: @John I'm not sure - I'll check. How would that impact this? Doesn't wireless isolation just prevent devices on the network from communicating to each other?

Comment: Isolation should not prevent outside connectivity in most cases, but I was just suggesting you check that.

Comment: @John Gotcha. I just checked and wireless isolation is turned off.

Comment: Maybe reset the router to default setting and update the firmware in it.

Comment: @John I have verified the firmware is up to date. I'll try to reset to factory defaults sometime when others aren't using the internet. I don't think I've changed too many settings so I wouldn't expect that to make a difference, but couldn't hurt I suppose.